# What is the significance of '?ngModel' when creating an AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working my way through the new ng-book. The chapter on filters includes a section on defining parsers with the following code:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('oneToTen', function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel';
```

The first time I've seen the '?ngModel' syntax, and the Angular API docs don't provide much help. What does this syntax signify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Required** can be explained as:

`[?][^][directiveName]`.

It is used to specify which directive controller should be used("inherited from"). So for instance a directive `<column-item>` needs to find the parent controller `<crtl-grid>`. There are a couple of symbols that can be used along with this attribute and they can also be combined:

^ = it indicates angular to seek up the DOM to find the directive.

? = it indicates angular that the directive is optional and angular will not throw an exception if not found.

So **?ngModel** is saying that the ngModel needs be declared along with this directive.

Answer (score 5):

`?` is optional directive and `^` is parent directive

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

```
(no prefix) - Locate the required controller on the current element. Throw an error if not found.
? - Attempt to locate the required controller or pass null to the link fn if not found.
^ - Locate the required controller by searching the element's parents. Throw an error if not found.
?^ - Attempt to locate the required controller by searching the element's parents or pass null to the link fn if not found.
```