# How to make ng-model as optional in angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-directive

I have a directive for which i want to make ng-model as optional.

I tried

```
return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    //......
}
```

I am using it like

```js
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {

  var getDialogTemplate = $attrs.cxDlgTemplateUrl;

  $scope.openDialog = function (confirmationAction) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      backdrop: 'static',
      templateUrl: getDialogTemplate,
      controller: $attrs.cxController,
      resolve: {
        dialogData: function () {
          return {
            dlgData: $ctrl.$modelValue
          };
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
      return confirmationAction();
    });
  };
}
```

still I get error while i am not giving value for ng-model when using the directive.

Comment: If `ngModel` is not set, then the 4th parameter to the `link` function will be null. What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20890266/1959948

Comment: I see that you call `dlgData: $ctrl.$modelValue` in your dialogData resolve.  You should probably change that to `dlgData: $ctrl && $ctrl.$modelValue`

Comment: I get error 'can not read property of undefined for $ctrl.$modelVlaue @ Matthias

Comment: I get the same error for your solution @JoseM

Comment: I tried angular.isDefined($ctrl) before return inside resolve solved my error.