# AngularJS directive "require" parameter

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('app').directive('perfBegin', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: ['$log', function($log) {
            var vm  = this;

            vm._perfBegin = performance.now();
        }]
    }
});

angular.module('app').directive('perfEnd', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^perfBegin',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, perf) {
            $log.log('Time (ms) = ' + (performance.now() - perf._perfBegin));
        }
    }
});
```

I want to use the above directive like this ...

```
<span perf-begin></span>

JS here

<span perf-end></span>
```

Is it possible to do this?
It seems AngularJS requires that I place my span within my span, which I'd rather not do.
What is difference between ^require and require ?

Comment: it is possible that this answers your question [What is the significance of '?ngModel' when creating an AngularJS directive?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20890266/1959948)

Comment: So to accomplish what I want to accomplish I need to inject a custom service? It appears this way ...

Answer (score 0):

No, require can't be used on sister elements.  What you can do is define a parent directive that is the parent of both sisters, and have each sister require the parent.

```
<div parent>
        <span sister1>
                ...
        </span>
        <span sister2>
                ...
        </span>
</div>
```

The difference between require ^parent vs require parent is that ^parent will search for the parent directive higher up the DOM tree. Require parent (without ^) searches the element that the directive is on.  In the above example, the use of ^parent is appropriate.